# What is the most diagrammatic proof that $gf = 0 \implies \text{im } f \subset \ker g$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, visualization, diagram-chasing

The proof of the following fact is trivial to most Arrow theorists / Linear algebraists, but I'm developing software that needs to "understand" in a sense this basic fact, because it is called upon all the time, so should be provable to the users of the software, in the software itself.

We are given the following diagram and the user is told that it commutes by definition.

[image: g of f commuting triangle equaling the zero morphism]

The goal diagram is the following:

[image: Ker g contains image space of f]

---

Using only the rules:

1. Definition of kernel / image: **What should we use here?**
2. Gluing two CD's along a common subdiagram and the resulting diagram is a CD.
3. Deleting arrows in a CD and the diagram will still be a CD.
4. You can compose along two paths in a CD with common endpoints and the resulting arrows are equal.
5. Any others we require.

---

So I'm wondering about the definition of Kernel / Image.  Clearly I'm using the one in which kernel / image are spaces, not maps.  What is the most light-weight, yet most diagrammatic definitions of these.

**Finally, how would the *diagrammatic* proof go given that, for example, the diagrams are of $R$-modules and $R$-module map?**.

To create a visual diagram I used https://q.uiver.app.  From there, create the diagram, turn off the grid and take a screenshot of it with Windows + Shift + S (or similar on other OS's), selecting a small region containing just the diagram, and then paste into the insert-image tool here.

*Note: in the system language, dashed arrow means "there exists" whereas a normal arrow means "for all such" if it doesn't appear in surrounding text or it is simply the exact thing that the surrounding text talks about.  So in the first diagram, $f,g$ both appear in the text, so they are "bound" whereas other variables might be "free to roam".*

---

**Edit.** I got the vocabulary of "free" vs "bound" variable backwards.  A bound variable is either a "there exists" or a "for all" variable for example (there are other variable-binding operators), where as a free variable is the one that occurs in the text for example "Definition of *equalizer morphism* $e$ is ..." so in the ... $e$ would be free.  We can think of this nicely as bound variables are introduced inside the "box of a diagram" whereas free variables are "free from the box" and are typically introduced outside of a diagram.

Comment: Please only use features of the syntax / semantics of the language that I have put down in the post.  If we require more than that, please state reason.

Comment: How far do you want to go? Abelian categories, exact categories or even extriangulated? The definition in abelian categories is probably what you  are looking for here

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace I have stipulated a category of $R$-modules.  So you can use abelian category definitions if you want or even go simpler

Comment: Then if you use the definition of kernel as a limit it is direct but it may be considered as cheating?

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace you could do that, but that's bringing in a lot of machinery.  I'm looking for more of a beginner-friendly analysis.    After all we're just trying to prove a definition!  So assume that I haven't yet implemented what a limit is or how diagrams behave under limits, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: For me, a somewhat "canonical" argument would look something like: $\operatorname{im}$ is defined in terms of an epi-mono factorization system, so you have a factorization $A \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{im}(f) \hookrightarrow B$.  Then, composing with $g$ gives zero; so by the definition of kernel, you have a factorization $A \to \ker(g)$.  And then, by epimorphisms being left-orthogonal to monomorphisms, you have a factorization $\operatorname{im}(f) \to \ker(g)$.  That morphism is a mono since its composition with $\ker(g) \to B$ is mono.  (Yes, probably more complex than you wanted.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler that sounds like it's it, but remember it has to be diagrammatic, so has to be done with gluing, deleting, etc.  Diagram "editing" operations.

Comment: So, the ingredients of that would be: the epi-mono factorization $A \twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{im}(f) \hookrightarrow B$ (make those dashed if you want); from $A \to B \overset{g}{\rightarrow} C$ giving zero, you get a dashed arrow $A \to \ker(g) \hookrightarrow B$; from a commutative square with left side an epi and right side a mono, draw a dashed line along the diagonal; and from a composition $A \to B \to C$ where the composition is a mono arrow, convert the $A \to B$ to a mono arrow.

Comment: Or, you could also use that if $A \twoheadrightarrow B \to C$ composes to 0, then the $B \to C$ map is 0; so in our situation $\operatorname{im}(f) \hookrightarrow B \to C$ is 0, giving a map $\operatorname{im}(f) \to \ker(g)$, and as before, use a composition being mono to convert this to a mono.

Comment: I don't see how you can have a useful language involving quantifiers ("there exist" and "for all") that doesn't have something to indicate the order of the quantifiers.

Comment: @RobArthan it's kind of like almost all of category theory theorems can be written in the form $\forall\forall\dots\forall \exists$ some diagram that commutes.  I reverse the challenge.  Show me something in category theory that cannot be encoded with unordered existential quantifiers.

Comment: How about the existence of products, or coproducts or equalisers or ... most other kinds of universal arrow? The defining property of the universal arrow is $\forall\exists$. The existence of a universal arrow for any diagram of a given shape is $\forall\exists\forall\exists$.

Comment: @RobArthan how I encode that in the system is with two diagrams - you don't want to overcomplicate a diagram anyway since that defeats the purpose; The first diagram says that equalizer $e : Z \to X$ (for example) exists such that $g \circ e = f \circ e$.  The second diagram says that if $e'$ does the same thing then (dashed arrow) there exists $u : Z' \to Z$ through which $e'$ factors as $e' = e \circ u$.    The first diagram "binds" the $e$.  In the second diagram, the $e'$ is a "free" meaning for any such arrow $e'$ that _its_ square commutes.     The diagrams $D, D'$ are connected via...

Comment: @RobArthan [...] logical AND.  That works because you can literally say there is a commutative diagram $D$ _such that_ the diagram $D'$ (together with its internal exists of $u$) commutes.  "Such that" everyone knows to be treatable as logical AND.  So while the system isn't perfectly matching traditional logic, the point is that it can encode enough of it in the above fashion to be useful as a tool / mnemonic.  Unique arrows get a "!" added to them or you could write $!u$ together with dashed arrow.

Comment: @RobArthan what a great question!

Comment: @RobArthan the true test will be if the user thinks the system is encoding what they think it should be.  That will be handled by converting all compound diagram content (statements) into English.  That's easy enough to do.

Comment: So we are agreed that $\forall\exists$ statements do not cover "almost all of category theory" . Your system apparently allows for that by nesting such statements using separate diagrams and some other notation explaining the logical dependencies between them. Presumably you also have some notation to determine whether one diagram means $\forall\exists$ or $\exists\forall$. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @RobArthan thanks.  Yes, you were right about this (so my first argument was incorrect).  But anway all diagram are assumed to be $\forall \exists$ so an $\exists \forall$ diagram would be encoded as two diagrams (or at least that is my current take).

Answer (score 1):

$$g(f(x))=0 \rightarrow f(x)\in\ker(g) \rightarrow \left\{ f(x)|x-is-in-domain\right\}\subset \ker(g)$$
$$Im(f)\subseteq \ker(g)$$

Comment: You should use $x \in \text{dom } f$.  But really this is not diagrammatic at all :|

Comment: @MathCrackExchange how do you write in the text font and not in math font?

Comment: I will teach you.  Right click on my math in my comment (or anywhere on MSE) and goto "Show Math As..." > "TeX Commands".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel Schepler in the comment section above, we have:

[image: Epi-mono factorization of a morphism]

as the definition of $\operatorname {im}f$.  I'm assuming there is only one such, which makes sense because otherwise $f'$ would not essentially be equal to $f$ and so on..

Now considering the usual definition of kernel $(\ker g = K) \xrightarrow{k} Y$ and applying that UMP to the following situation works:

[image: Complicated diagram involving kernel of g as an equalizer with zero and an epi-mono factorization of f]

Though for the sake of the user I would definitely break this up into more steps.